# Reciprocal Fibonacci constant

Tags: code-golf, math, fibonacci

Seeing as there have been an awful lot of normal Fibonacci challenges, I decided that it might be interesting to calculate the [Reciprocal Fibonacci constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant) - namely, the sum of the reciprocals of the Fibonacci sequence.

The challenge is to calculate the Reciprocal Fibonacci constant with the number of Fibonacci series to use digit given as input, i.e. an input of 10 means to calculate based on the reciprocals of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers.  In the likely case of a tie, shortest code wins.

The winner will be chosen in three weeks via standard code-golf rules.

Comment: This is equal (if I've understood it right) to 1/φ (reciprocal of golden ratio). If you want us to actually use the Fibonacci numbers in the calculation, you should specify. If not, there's certainly languages where `φ` is a builtin. (not APL for a change)

Comment: @marinus Changed.

Comment: @marinus, it's not equal to 1/phi. It does have a closed form, but it's [quite tricky](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html). Mathematica probably has a built-in, but I doubt many other languages do.

Comment: @OP, "highest accuracy possible" is a useless winning criterion. Anyone who has a language which supports arbitrary decimal precision, or who can be bothered to write the support for it, can make an implementation with a precision parameter and then engage in an edit war to increase that parameter. It would make more sense to ask for a function which takes the precision as a parameter. Judging on speed is also tricky, because it depends on many factors (CPU model, RAM available, system load, ...).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is this better?

Comment: That's one way to improve it. You could probably remove the last rule now, because any approach which doesn't require adding the inverses of the numbers themselves is going to be very interesting.

Comment: What is the winning criteria?

Comment: @Quincunx Sorry, it was removed during question modification.

Comment: @Quincunx Fixed now.

Comment: For comparison, the answer I would have submitted to an earlier version of the question which asked for the constant per se: `import java.math.*;public class C{public static void main(String[]_){MathContext C=new MathContext(110);BigDecimal I=BigDecimal.ONE,a=I,b=I,s=I,S,x,y;int n=11;while(n-->1){b=I.subtract(a);s=a.subtract(b);a=a.pow(2).add(I).divide(s,C);}S=I.divide(b.negate(),C);while(++n<20){x=b.divide(a,C).pow(n);y=x.divide(a,C);S=S.add(I.divide(I.subtract(x),C).add(y.divide(I.subtract(y),C)).multiply(y.pow(n)));}System.out.println(S.multiply(s,C));}}`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for helping me.  I seem to keep making different blunders.  Fortunately, they have been more and more minor (it seems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**K (19)**

(or 17 if you skip defining it as a function)

```
f:{+/*+%x(|+\)\|!2}
```

Tested on Kona.

Basically, it generates the first x values of the fibonacci sequence into an array (without using builtins), divides 1 by each value of the entire array, transposes and sums it up.

(thanks to @tmartin for the better sum method)

Comment: A slight variation on yours for 17 chars -- `{+/*+%x(|+\)\|!2}`

Comment: @tmartin Thanks, yes, that was a less convoluted sum method :)

Answer (score 9):

### Perl - 35 bytes

```
print!map$\-=1/($%+=$.=$%-$.),0..<>
```

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 10 | perl inv-fib-sum.pl
3.34170499581934
```

---

### Further Analysis

It's interesting to note that the sum

[image]

is convergent. Supposing we wanted to calculate a few thousand digits or so, the naïve approach is almost sufficient. The convergence is quite slow at first, but speeds up rapidly, so that *1000* digits only takes about *4800* terms. A sample Python implementation might be:

```
a=[1,1]
for i in range(4800):a=[a[0]+a[1]]+a
z=10**1000
print sum(map(lambda i:z/i,a))
```

which after a second or so outputs:

```
33598856662431775531720113029189271796889051337319684864955538153251303189966833836154162164567900872970453429288539133041367890171008836795913517330771190785803335503325077531875998504871797778970060395645092153758927752656733540240331694417992939346109926262579646476518686594497102165589843608814726932495910794738736733785233268774997627277579468536769185419814676687429987673820969139012177220244052081510942649349513745416672789553444707777758478025963407690748474155579104200675015203410705335285129792635242062267537568055761955669720848843854407983324292851368070827522662579751188646464096737461572387236295562053612203024635409252678424224347036310363201466298040249015578724456176000319551987905969942029178866949174808096746523682654086938399069873211752166957063859411814553647364268782462926166650100098903804823359519893146150108288726392887669917149304053057745574321561167298985617729731395370735291966884327898022165047585028091806291002444277017460241040417786069190065037142832933
```

(The last four digits don't quite converge, but we'll ignore that for now.)

Let's try to speed up the convergence a bit. A standard trick is to use [Euler's Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform). After expansion and simplification, this produces a nicer result:

[image]

It should be fairly apparent why this converges more quickly; each term has 3 terms in the denominator rather than just one. Calculating *1000* digits takes only *1600* (one third as many) terms:

```
a=[1,1]
for i in range(1601):a=[a[0]+a[1]]+a
z=10**1000
print sum(map(lambda i:(-1)**i*z/(a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]),range(1601)))
```

Output:

```
3598856662431775531720113029189271796889051337319684864955538153251303189966833836154162164567900872970453429288539133041367890171008836795913517330771190785803335503325077531875998504871797778970060395645092153758927752656733540240331694417992939346109926262579646476518686594497102165589843608814726932495910794738736733785233268774997627277579468536769185419814676687429987673820969139012177220244052081510942649349513745416672789553444707777758478025963407690748474155579104200675015203410705335285129792635242062267537568055761955669720848843854407983324292851368070827522662579751188646464096737461572387236295562053612203024635409252678424224347036310363201466298040249015578724456176000319551987905969942029178866949174808096746523682654086938399069873211752166957063859411814553647364268782462926166650100098903804823359519893146150108288726392887669917149304053057745574321561167298985617729731395370735291966884327898022165047585028091806291002444277017460241040417786069190065037142834500
```

(Here again, the last 4 digits don't converge.)

We're not quite done yet. If we combine adjacent terms, we end up with the following:

[image]

Factoring out each term from the remainder of the summation gives the nested expression:

[image]

Now we're getting somewhere. Notice that the numerators of follow [OEIS A206351](http://oeis.org/A206351) (with the exception of the first term, which is doubled):

[image]

and the denominators follow [OEIS A081016](http://oeis.org/A081016) (shifted by one term):

[image]

Each of these have very simple recurrence relations, namely:

[image]

and

[image]

respectively. Putting it all together, we find that we need only *800* iterations for *1000* digits:

```
b,c=[16,3,1],[273,40,3]
for i in range(800):b,c=[7*b[0]-b[1]-4]+b,[7*c[0]-c[1]-1]+c
s=z=10**1000
for x,y in zip(b,c):s=(z+s)*x/y
print s
```

which outputs:

```
3598856662431775531720113029189271796889051337319684864955538153251303189966833836154162164567900872970453429288539133041367890171008836795913517330771190785803335503325077531875998504871797778970060395645092153758927752656733540240331694417992939346109926262579646476518686594497102165589843608814726932495910794738736733785233268774997627277579468536769185419814676687429987673820969139012177220244052081510942649349513745416672789553444707777758478025963407690748474155579104200675015203410705335285129792635242062267537568055761955669720848843854407983324292851368070827522662579751188646464096737461572387236295562053612203024635409252678424224347036310363201466298040249015578724456176000319551987905969942029178866949174808096746523682654086938399069873211752166957063859411814553647364268782462926166650100098903804823359519893146150108288726392887669917149304053057745574321561167298985617729731395370735291966884327898022165047585028091806291002444277017460241040417786069190065037142835294
```

(Here, finally, the last 4 digits converge correctly.)

But that's still not quite everything. If we observe the intermediate values for *s*, we find that it converges to a different value entirely before converging on the actual convergence point. The reason for this is the following:

[image]

Solving for a stable *s*, we find that:

[image]

Because this is a simple root, we can use [Newton's Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html) to get us most of the way there, and then jump in at a much later point in the iteration. Only about *400* digits of precision are necessary (as the *b* and *c* values aren't any larger than that anyway), which can be achieved with just *7* iterations, while saving *320* iterations of the main loop:

```
b,c=[16,3,1],[273,40,3]
for i in range(480):b,c=[7*b[0]-b[1]-4]+b,[7*c[0]-c[1]-1]+c
z=10**1000;s=z/17
for i in range(7):s-=(s*s+s*z-z*z/16)/(2*s+z)
for x,y in zip(b,c):s=(z+s)*x/y
print s
```

Output is identical to the previous, runtime is about 0.02s on my system using PyPy v2.1. Even though it needs one tenth the number of iterations as the original, it's significantly faster than 10x due to multiplying and dividing by much smaller terms. I don't think much more can be tweaked out of it, although I'd be happy to be shown wrong.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica (32 characters without built-in Fibonacci)

```
Tr[1/⌈(.5+√5/2)^Range@#/√5-.5⌉]&
```

[image]

Here I used the rounding formula for Fibonacci numbers

[image]

where `φ` is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 5):

### Kona (<strike>25</strike> 21)

```
{+/%(x(|+\)\1 1)[;1]}
```

Probably could be made smaller by experts, but I am still learning the language.

```
  f 10
3.341705
  f 3
2.8333
  f 25
3.359872
  f 400
3.359886
```

The last one didn't actually take any more time than the others.

Comment: I am learning some languages by completing challenges in them.  Nice to see that I am not the only one.

Comment: Save yourself two characters by just calling the function as a lambda rather than a named function. Then save a further two by using `%` as the reciprocal function rather than doing `1.%` -- `{+/%(x(|+\)\1 1)[;1]}` for 21 chars

Comment: @tmartin: Odd...I thought I tried doing reciprocal and was getting 0 because of integer division, but it is currently working for me. I'm updating the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you're computing the right sum? I get 2.833333333 for n=4, for example, instead of 3. One of us is wrong!

Comment: @Tobia: A difference between 0 and 1 indexing. `f 0` results in `1.0`, `f 1 -> 2.0` and so on.

Comment: Well, it does say "an input of 10 means to calculate based on the reciprocals of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers"…

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <s>30</s>  24

With 6 characters saved thanks to ybeltukov.

```
 Tr[1/Fibonacci@Range@#]&
```

---

Before adding the terms:

```
1/Fibonacci@Range@#&[20]
```

[image: image1]

---

With addition included:

```
 Tr[1/Fibonacci@Range@#]&[20]
```

[image: image2]

Comment: `Fibonacci` is `Listable` :) It can be reduced to `Tr[1/Fibonacci@Range@#]&`

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 21 chars/bytes*

```
{+/÷{↑+\∘⌽⍣⍵⊢0 1}¨⍳⍵}
```

**Example**

```
      {+/÷{↑+\∘⌽⍣⍵⊢0 1}¨⍳⍵} 10
3.330469041
      ⍪{+/÷{↑+\∘⌽⍣⍵⊢0 1}¨⍳⍵}¨⍳10
1          
2          
2.5        
2.833333333
3.033333333
3.158333333
3.23525641 
3.282875458
3.312287223
3.330469041
      {+/÷{↑+\∘⌽⍣⍵⊢0 1}¨⍳⍵} 100
3.359885666
```

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 33

*Input:* `n = 10`

```
s=f=t=1;for(;n--;)t+=1/(s+=f=s-f)
```

Based in my first post in Perl, here is the result directly from the *Google Chrome Console*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## K, 22

...

```
{+/%x#x{x,+/-2#x}/1 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 27 bytes

```perl6
{sum 1 X/(1,&[+]...*)[^$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFfBUCFCX8NQRy1aO1ZPT09LMzpOJT629n9xYqVCmoahgYGBpvV/AA)

Alternatively

```perl6
{sum 1 xx$_ Z/(1,&[+]...*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFfBUKGiQiVeIUpfw1BHLVo7Vk9PT0uz9n9xYqVCmoahgYGBpvV/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1309), 35

*Runs on a TI-84 calculator*

```
1→Y:0→X`N4;N,1,N~1/X:Y→Z:X+Y→Y:Z→X&
```

- Store `1` in `Y` and `0` in `X`
- Take `N` as input
- Initialize a `For` loop
- Display `X`
- Store `Y` in `Z` and `X+Y` in `Y`
- Store `Z` in `X`
- End the `For` loop

Comment: I assume it works, but can you provide an explanation?

Comment: I've added one.

Answer (score 2):

## PERL, <s>62</s> 43

```
$s=$t=1;$t+=1/($a=$f+$s),$f=$s,$s=$a,for 0..<>;say $t
```

**Edit:**

After some more time looking at my code I was able to save 19 chars:

```
$s=1;$t+=1/($s+=$f=$s-$f)for 0..<>;say $t+2
```

> input: 10
>   > 3.35294128575734

Answer (score 2):

## BC - 116

```
define f(n){if(n < 2){return n;}else{return f(n-1)+f(n-2);}}
define r(n){for(i=1;i<n;++i){m=m+(1/f(i));};return m;}
```

call r(n) with n to solve. The precision can be set arbitrarily, so this is the most accurate solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, 64

```
: r 1 1 rot 1e 0 do 2dup - nip tuck + dup s>f 1/f f+ swap loop ;
```

usage:

```
10 r f. 3.34170499581934  ok
100 r f. 3.35988566624318  ok
1000 r f. 3.35988566624318  ok
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python (<s>55</s> 51)

```
i,r=p=1,1
while i<n+1:r+=1./p[-1];p=p[1],sum(p);i+=1
r
```

```
i,r,a,b=[1]*4
while i<n+1:r+=1./b;a,b=b,b+a;i+=1
r
```

In interactive mode:

```
n=10
3.341704995819338

n=100
```

```
3.3598856429940778
```

```
3.359885666243178

n=400
```

```
3.3598855578800064
```

```
3.359885666243178
```

Answer (score 1):

**RPL (HP 49G/G+/50g), 50 bytes**

```
« 0. 1. DUP2 5. ROLL
  START SWAP OVER + ROT OVER INV + UNROT
  NEXT DROP2
»
```

Examples:

10 -> 3.33046904076

11 -> 3.34170499582

30 -> 3.35988372158

55 -> 3.35988566622

In theory, the sum of the first 55 digits would give 12 correct digits. The last digit should be '4' instead of '2'. This should be fixed by adding up the terms backwards, but the code would be slightly longer.

If the constant were to be computed to 1000 decimal places using the definition  the sum should be carried out to at least the first 4790 terms, which would take too much time on the HP 50g, if possible at all. For this task a more efficient method is required, like the one used in the following RPL program (464 bytes, checksum # 207Eh) whose argument is the desired number of decimal places:

```
%%HP: T(3)A(R)F(.);
\<< PUSH RAD -105 CF -3 CF R\->I DUP 1 + 2 INV SWAP 100 LN * 5 LN + OVER ASINH / \v/ * CEIL DUP 2 MOD + DUP 0 ROT
[[ 1 1 ]
 [ 1 0 ]] SWAP DUP2 ^ 3 GETI UNROT GET 4 ROLLD 4 ROLLD DUP + ^ 1 GETI UNROT GET 1 + 0 1 8 ROLL 2 /
  START PICK3 + DUP PICK3 * NEG 6 PICK SQ + / 4 PICK SQ * EXPAND ROT PICK3 - ROT OVER - ROT 6 ROLL 6 ROLL 6 ROLL + LASTARG * LASTARG 5 ROLLD 5 ROLLD / + ROT PICK3 - ROT OVER - 6 ROLL 6 ROLL 6 ROLL
  NEXT ROT + INV 5 ROLL + EXPAND 4 ROLLD 3 DROPN FXND PICK3 ALOG OVER - PICK3 * SWAP IQUOT + \->STR DUP HEAD -51 FC? { "." } { "," } IFTE + SWAP TAIL + 1 ROT 2 + SUB POP
\>>

'RFC' STO
```

1000 RFC -->

3.3598856662431775531720113029189271796889051337319684864955538153251303189966833836154162164567900872970453429288539133041367890171008836795913517330771190785803335503325077531875998504871797778970060395645092153758927752656733540240331694417992939346109926262579646476518686594497102165589843608814726932495910794738736733785233268774997627277579468536769185419814676687429987673820969139012177220244052081510942649349513745416672789553444707777758478025963407690748474155579104200675015203410705335285129792635242062267537568055761955669720848843854407983324292851368070827522662579751188646464096737461572387236295562053612203024635409252678424224347036310363201466298040249015578724456176000319551987905969942029178866949174808096746523682654086938399069873211752166957063859411814553647364268782462926166650100098903804823359519893146150108288726392887669917149304053057745574321561167298985617729731395370735291966884327898022165047585028091806291002444277017460241040417786069190065037142835294

(22 min 23 sec, on the real HP 50g)

---

For one thousand digits the first 50 terms of the series plus another 50 terms of a continued fraction are evaluated, two at a time in only 25 iterations (48 terms of each would have sufficed, though). An equivalent DECIMAL BASIC program takes just 10 milliseconds on my computer (Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo CPU E4700 @ 2.6 GHz).

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-mx`, 6 bytes

```
1/MgUÄ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MS9NZ1XE&input=MTAwMAotbXg=)

Answer (score 1):

## JAEL, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Changing the diacritics from one character to another gave me 1 byte

Still working on SBCS encoding.

```
#`&@uȦ
```

#### Explanation (generated automatically):

```
./jael -u explain '#`&@uȦ'

ORIGINAL CODE:
#`&@uȦ

EXPANDING EXPLANATION:
Ȧ => .a!

EXPANDED CODE:
#`&@u.a!

COMPLETED CODE:
#`&@u.a!,


#       ,               repeat (p1) times:
 `                              stack 1
  &                             push number of iterations of this loop
   @                            push nth fibonacci number
    u                           push p2 / p1
     .                          push the value under the tape head
      a                         push p1 + p2
       !                        write p1 to the tapehead
         ␄              print machine state
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I miscounted it.

Comment: I know the language is optimised for characters, but this site scores by bytes, so it's misleading to include the character count

Comment: You can get 8 bytes if you don't compress `u.`. On the topic of an SBCS, you might have trouble because your docs list over 600 commands or combinations of commands, and a SBCS language can only have 256 single byte commands. On the other hand, there's a large number of useless one to one translations...

Comment: Yes @JoKing, you are right. I started the whole idea a while ago and didn't consider that it would affect the byte size. Now I'm writing my undergraduate thesis on top of JAEL and it's too late to reconsider some decisions (I'm presenting it by the end of november). About the command list: yes, it was automatically generated and I didn't give it enough attention. As this is my first project on this area, I'll gather experience and try to learn from the bad decisions. Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```cs
a=>{double r=1,x=1,y=1,i=0;for(;++i<a;y+=x,x=y-x)r+=1/y;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFETX9ivuMqX1Ud0IaQQRBEE3KriO6a0EagI3qTSUfnsNlA4chsMsRrmlsoRj67T5wCM4j18OqpHOwRH6xHnptYJza1RZ2fbdYA5TH6AGMUpx6CcHEkXeRUJEiw2vLTGeZbqUPGSii1tYdillolgHTuhbMkB8GPl88rO6gpvUhqV9sjhZ42yDqxdpj6xm0X9IfvW0F@N3Wzbvd5TVVRtkaQxPhmHc/wE)

Can't use floats because of imprecision.

Example where input = 8:

- double: 3.28287545787546 (rounds to 3.282875)
- float:  3.282876 (off by 0.000001)

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    double r = 1,                       // initialize r (sum of reciprocals) - start at 1 to save one byte in for loop
            x = 1, y = 1,                   // initialize x (2nd largest Fibonacci) and y (largest Fibonacci)
            i = 0;                          // initialize i (loop counter)
    for(; ++i < a; y += x, x = y - x)   // from 1 to a, while incrementing the Fibonacci numbers
        r += 1 / y;                         // increment the reciprocal Fibonacci
    return r;                           // return the reciprocal Fibonacci
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
;/b$
=1:Z+Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/31o/SYXL1tAqSjvy/39DAwMDAA)

### Explanation

```
;          The sum of the first n terms of the sequence
 /         which are 1 divided by
  b$       the nth term in the sequence on the second line

=1:Z+Y     Fibonacci with starting indexes 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
RÆḞİS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ocNvDHfOObAj@//@/KQA)

#### How it works

```
RÆḞİS    Main link (monad). Input: integer
R        Range
 ÆḞ      nth Fibonacci number
   İ     Reciprocal
    S    Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 24 bytes

```ruby
:+|:sum+(:++[0,1]|:/&1r)
```

Returns a fraction. If a floating point number is necessary, change `1r` to `1.0` for +1 byte.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWO6y0a6yKS3O1Nay0taMNdAxja6z01QyLNCHSKwtKS4oV3KJNYyH8BQsgNAA)

### Explanation

J-uby's `+` operator, when called with a function and initial array like `fn + arr`, returns a function that, when called with an integer `n` (like `(fn + arr).(n)`), applies `fn` to the last `arr.size` items in `arr` `n` times, making it very handy for Fibonacci and similar sequences.

```
:+ | :sum + (:+ + [0,1] | :/ & 1r)
:+ |                                # Range 1..input, then
     :sum + (                    )  # sum of...
             :+ + [0,1] |           #   nth fibonacci number, then
                          :/ & 1r   #   reciprocal
```